# Visualforce Help Text Background Color

Tags: visualforce, helptext

I have a Visualforce page that utilizes a help orb to mimic the standard Salesforce help orb.  All works properly, but I would like to change the background color of the pop-up help box.  Does anyone know how I can do this? My code for the orb is below:

```
<span class="helpButton" id="Name-_help">
     <img src="/s.gif" alt="" class="helpOrb" title="{!$Label.DS_RichTextHelpText}"/>
</span><p/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the style attribute as below.

```
<span class="helpButton" id="Name-_help" style="background-color: yellow;">
     <img src="/s.gif" alt="" class="helpOrb" title="{!$Label.DS_RichTextHelpText}"/>
</span><p/>
```

> Update

Here I have tried to mimic the Salesforce help style with the help of the “helpOrb” class supplied by the standard SFDC stylesheets.

```
<apex:page >
    <style>
        .vfHelpText a {
            position:relative;
        }
        .vfHelpText a span {
            display: none;
        }
        .vfHelpText a:hover span {
            display: block;
            position:absolute;
            top:1.25em;
            padding:2px 5px;
            left:-15em; width:15em;
            z-index:100;
            border:1px solid orange;
            background-color:#FEFDB9;
            color:black;
        }
    </style>
    <span class="vfHelpText">
        <apex:outputLink value="javascript:return false;">
            <img src="/s.gif" alt="" class="helpOrb" />
            <span>{!$Label.DS_RichTextHelpText}</span>
        </apex:outputLink>
    </span>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did try that but it only changes the background of the orb icon itself, not the text box that appears when a user hovers on the orb icon.

Comment: Can you please explain how the textbox comes into picture? Is it through javascript?

Comment: No.  I don't have any other code besides what I posted.  I believe it's the standard Salesforce functionality.

Comment: Please find my updated solution. I think you are looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [CSS style](http://htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/) whose selector matches the ID of the `<span>`.

Example:

```
<style>
  #Name-_help {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<span class="helpButton" id="Name-_help">
     <img src="/s.gif" alt="" class="helpOrb" title="{!$Label.DS_RichTextHelpText}"/>
</span><p/>
```

Comment: Note that this approach is considered [better practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css) than directly adding the `style` attribute to the `span` element.

Comment: Rob, thanks.  However, that changes the background color of the actual help orb.  I want to change the background color of the help text box that pops up when the user hovers on the orb.